# Exception was caught during Core Data change processing

Tags: core-data

In my application, I create my `CoreDataStack` in `AppDelegate` and pass that instance to my root view controller. In the view controller, I connect to an API, retrieve & parse some JSON, and then save to Core Data. However, for about one out of every ten launches, I get a crash immediately, which happens here, in my `CoreDataStack` class:

```swift
func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil

        // This if-statement is the line that gets highlighted following the crash.
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

The log I get is:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  
Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  
-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2015-07-19 11:33:06.115 AppName[210:3907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
```

In my view controller, I am getting to the main thread in order to save to Core Data. Following the crash, when navigating through the stack in the Debug Navigator, `self.coreDataStack!.saveContext()` is what gets highlighted. I assumed that I was trying to create and access the `managedObjectContext` on different threads, but that doesn't seem to be the case because when I call `println(NSThread.currentThread()`, I get the same thread number and name as I do when I print from `AppDelegate`, where I create the `CoreDataStack` instance.

```swift
func updateStockInformation(#completion: ((finished: Bool) -> Void)?) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    if stocks.count > 0 {
        var numberOfStocksUpdated = 0
        for stock in stocks {
            yql.query(stock.symbol, completion: { (results) -> Void in
                if results != nil {
                    if let query = results!["query"] as? NSDictionary, results = query["results"] as? NSDictionary, quote = results["quote"] as? NSDictionary, lastTradePrice = quote["LastTradePriceOnly"] as? NSString {
                        if let change = quote["Change"] as? NSString {
                            var changeValue = NSDecimalNumber()
                            if (change as String).hasPrefix("-") {
                                let unsignedNegativeString = change.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
                                let unsignedNegativeNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: unsignedNegativeString)
                                let signedNegativeNumber = unsignedNegativeNumber.negative()
                                changeValue = signedNegativeNumber
                            } else {
                                let unsignedPositiveString = change.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "")
                                let unsignedPositiveNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: unsignedPositiveString)
                                changeValue = unsignedPositiveNumber
                            }
                            if self.market.status == .Open {
                                stock.change = changeValue
                            }
                        }
                        var priceValue = NSDecimalNumber()
                        // Change the 'lastTradePrice' value from an NSString into an NSDecimalNumber
                        priceValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: lastTradePrice as String)
                        stock.lastTradePrice = priceValue
                        stock.profitFromStocksInCompany = self.updateProfitForStock(stock)
                        numberOfStocksUpdated += 1
                    }
                }
                if numberOfStocksUpdated == self.stocks.count {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        println("MainViewController - updateStockInformation: \(NSThread.currentThread())")
                        println()
                        self.coreDataStack!.saveContext()
                        self.updateTotalProfitLabel()
                        self.reloadPageViewController()
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false 
                        self.stockInformationUpdatedDelegate?.stockInformationDidUpdate(self.market.getStatusOfMarket())
                        completion?(finished: true)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing incorrectly to get this occasional crash?

Answer (score 0):

As I was printing out the JSON data, I noticed that everything was coming back all jumbled, which meant that the for-loop was quickly sending out the network request before the previous network request's data was received and parsed. So I decided to restructure my code and use recursion. Here is the newly restructured code that uses recursion to update the information of a stock only after the information from the previous stock has been received, parsed, and updated:

```swift
func updateStockInformation(#completion: ((finished: Bool) -> Void)?) {
    updateStock(0, completion: nil)
    if stocksUpdatingAppBecameActive {
        stocksUpdatingAppBecameActive = false
    }
}



func updateStock(stockIndex: Int, completion: ((finished: Bool) -> Void)?) {
    var stockIndex = stockIndex
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    if stocks.count > 0 {
        let stock = stocks[stockIndex]
        yql.query(stock.symbol, completion: { (results) -> Void in
            if results != nil {
                if let query = results!["query"] as? NSDictionary, results = query["results"] as? NSDictionary, quote = results["quote"] as? NSDictionary, lastTradePrice = quote["LastTradePriceOnly"] as? NSString {
                    if let change = quote["Change"] as? NSString {
                        var changeValue = NSDecimalNumber()
                        // Change the 'change' value from an NSString into an NSDecimalNumber
                        if (change as String).hasPrefix("-") {
                            let unsignedNegativeString = change.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
                            let unsignedNegativeNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: unsignedNegativeString)
                            let signedNegativeNumber = unsignedNegativeNumber.negative()
                            changeValue = signedNegativeNumber
                        } else {
                            let unsignedPositiveString = change.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "")
                            let unsignedPositiveNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: unsignedPositiveString)
                            changeValue = unsignedPositiveNumber
                        }
                        if self.market.status == .Open {
                            stock.change = changeValue
                        }
                    }
                    var priceValue = NSDecimalNumber()
                    priceValue = NSDecimalNumber(string: lastTradePrice as String)
                    stock.lastTradePrice = priceValue
                    stock.profitFromStocksInCompany = self.updateProfitForStock(stock)
                    self.numberOfStocksUpdated += 1
                }
            }
            if self.numberOfStocksUpdated == self.stocks.count {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.coreDataStack!.saveContext()
                    self.updateTotalProfitLabel()
                    self.reloadPageViewController()
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                    self.stockInformationUpdatedDelegate?.stockInformationDidUpdate(self.market.getStatusOfMarket())
                    self.numberOfStocksUpdated = 0
                    completion?(finished: true)
                })
            } else {
                self.updateStock(stockIndex + 1, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```